# How to let pyenv to find installed python versions

Tags: python, installation, pyenv

I experience a following contradictory problem with [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv):

```
$ pyenv global python2.7.10
pyenv: version `python2.7.10' not installed
$ pyenv install 2.7.10
pyenv: /Users/xeli/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10 already exists
continue with installation? (y/N)
```

Also:

```
$ python2.7
pyenv: python2.7: command not found

The `python2.7' command exists in these Python versions:
  2.7.10
```

The shims are on the PATH as required:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/xeli/.pyenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Nothing suspicious in the shims directory:

```
$ ls ~/.pyenv/shims | grep python2
ipython2
python2
python2-config
python2.6
python2.6-config
python2.7
python2.7-config
```

In my `.profile` I have:

```
export PYENV_ROOT=~/.pyenv
if which pyenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv init -)"; fi
```

Therefore pyenv should be initialized at startup.

I cannot figure out how to solve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`pyenv` seems to require explicit `.python-version` file to be set in the current directory for any other version than the default in `.pyenv/version`. This is explained in [a closed GitHub issue](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/34).

The problem is fixed by creating `.python-version` file. This is done automatically for example by `$ pyenv local 2.7.10`.

The initial problem therefore is in the poor error message. I created [a new issue](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/566) to fix it.

Comment: `~/.python-version`?

Answer (score 24):

Short answer — all you need to do is:

```
pyenv global 2.7.10
```

pyenv’s name for the Python 2.7.10 interpreter version is just `2.7.10`, not `python2.7.10`.  You can get a list of all your installed versions with:

```
pyenv versions
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a version installed and then later uninstalled it, but the version reference remained in `.pyenv/version`. Error went away once I manually removed it from there.