# pyenv: python :command not found

Tags: python, pyenv

I want to use Python3 with pyenv.

```sh
$ pyenv root
/Users/asari/.pyenv
$ pyenv versions
  system
  2.7.15
  3.6.2
  3.6.3
  3.6.4
* 3.6.6 (set by /Users/asari/workspace/hoge/.python-version)
$ python -V
pyenv: python: command not found

The `python' command exists in these Python versions:
  2.7.15
```

but, python command not found.

I read it in `.pyenv/shims/python`, thought that there was not python in `.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/bin/`, but I did not know why python was missing.

```sh
$ pwd
/Users/asari/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/bin
$ ls -la
total 12096
drwxr-xr-x  19 asari  staff      608  8 16 00:51 .
drwxr-xr-x   6 asari  staff      192  8 16 00:51 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 asari  staff        8  8 16 00:51 2to3 -> 2to3-3.6
-rwxr-xr-x   1 asari  staff      135  8 16 00:51 2to3-3.6
-rwxr-xr-x   1 asari  staff      276  8 16 00:51 easy_install-3.6
lrwxr-xr-x   1 asari  staff        7  8 16 00:51 idle3 -> idle3.6
-rwxr-xr-x   1 asari  staff      133  8 16 00:51 idle3.6
-rwxr-xr-x   1 asari  staff      258  8 16 00:51 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x   1 asari  staff      258  8 16 00:51 pip3.6
lrwxr-xr-x   1 asari  staff        8  8 16 00:51 pydoc3 -> pydoc3.6
-rwxr-xr-x   1 asari  staff      118  8 16 00:51 pydoc3.6
lrwxr-xr-x   1 asari  staff        9  8 16 00:51 python3 -> python3.6
lrwxr-xr-x   1 asari  staff       16  8 16 00:51 python3-config -> python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x   2 asari  staff  3078944  8 16 00:51 python3.6
lrwxr-xr-x   1 asari  staff       17  8 16 00:51 python3.6-config -> python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x   2 asari  staff  3078944  8 16 00:51 python3.6m
-rwxr-xr-x   1 asari  staff     2076  8 16 00:51 python3.6m-config
lrwxr-xr-x   1 asari  staff       10  8 16 00:51 pyvenv -> pyvenv-3.6
-rwxr-xr-x   1 asari  staff      475  8 16 00:51 pyvenv-3.6
```

$PATH

```
$ echo $PATH | perl -p -e 's/:/\n/g'
/Users/asari/.pyenv/shims
/Users/asari/.pyenv/bin
/Users/asari/.rbenv/shims
/Users/asari/.cargo/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

install log

```sh
$ pyenv install 3.6.6
python-build: use openssl from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.6.6.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.3/Python-3.6.3.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.6.6...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Installed Python-3.6.6 to /Users/asari/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6
```

```sh
$ pyenv --version
pyenv 1.2.7
$ brew list | grep py
python
python@2
```

pyenv clone and installed from github(I have not installed pyenv on brew)

.zshrc

```
# python
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

Thank you for your time.

**UPDATE**

I created `python` 's symlink, and python worked.

Why is there no `python` s symlink?
(I was wondering if install failed, I am running install and uninstall many times

create symlink

```
$ pwd
/Users/asari/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/bin
$ ln -s python3 python
```

Work,

```
$ pwd
/Users/asari/workspace/hoge
$ python -V
Python 3.6.6
```

Comment: What are you typing these commands into? Did you set `>>>` as your zsh prompt?

Comment: Yes, `>>>` is zsh prompt.

Comment: what contains `/Users/asari/.pyenv/bin` ?

Comment: because it was written by README. https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: should it be the `.zshenv` file, instead of `.zshrc`? `Zsh note: Modify your ~/.zshenv file instead of ~/.bash_profile` in [link](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Comment: Setting your shell prompt to `>>>` is a bad idea. It becomes difficult to tell whether you're in Python or the shell at any given time, both for you and for anyone trying to help you.

Comment: Changed shell prompt to `$`. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

I used the following grep option in `.zshrc`

```
export GREP_OPTIONS = '- color = auto'
```

It seems that even if ANSI escape code was included in the search result of grep used in `pyenv`, it was not used properly as a character string.

I think that you all know, but `GREP_OPTIONS` is deprecated.

Comment: Did not work for me.

Answer (score 37):

Added to ~/.bashrc

```
alias python="$(pyenv which python)"
alias pip="$(pyenv which pip)"
```

Comment: Works, but it seems you need to run this again if you activate a different pyenv?

Comment: Using these kind of aliases can cause unforseen problems. E.g. it will prevent a virtual environment to be activated incorrectly when you e.g. run `pipenv shell`. Instead simply ensure that the shims for `python` and `pip` are in your path - by ensuring that `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` is being executed in your `.bash_profile` or `.zprofile`.

Comment: This is indeed problematic. @arno_v's answer - basically read the docs - should be the accepted and most voted one!

Comment: just logged in to tell you that you saved me

Answer (score 26):

Under mac OS `10.15`

We add the following to `.bashrc` file or `.zshrc` file

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PATH"

if which pyenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv init -)"; fi
```

Answer (score 18):

For me the config in my `.zshrc.local` file needed an update. Using the info on [configure your shell's environment for Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation) page I changed the pyenv init stuff to this:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"

eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"

# Optionally (when you use pyenv virtualenv)
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Comment: Curious why `source ~/.bashrc` the bash config file inside zsh config? Are you using `.zshrc.local` as a common config for both shells? Seems very specific to your setup and could cause issues on other people's systems e.g if they have bash specific syntax in a `~/.bashrc` file on their system. The `virtualenv-init` part also relates to a plugin that others might not use.

Comment: Very good questions. It seems the source `.bashrc` is not even used on my systems (I copy pasted it from the pyenv docs, but I see they've updated that in the meantime as well).

I'll update the answer a bit :)

Comment: @asari-mtr you should mark this as the correct answer. My earlier comment no longer applies.

Answer (score 8):

on MAC OS. I solved it by adding to below lines to the `~/.bash_profile`

At the terminal call `vi ~/.bash_profile`

Insert 2 below lines

```
alias python="$(pyenv which python)"
alias pip="$(pyenv which pip)"
```

Call this command after saving above file `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: This is a copy of the incorrect answer posted by @4lk4tr43 4 months earlier, just with a different config file. It is not a good solution as commented there. The problem is you don't have the shims directory in your path, e.g. this: `export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PATH"`.  Proof: set your global pyenv `pyenv global 3.11` then set this alias `alias python="$(pyenv which python)"` now check where `python` points to `which python`, now change global version `pyenv global 3.9` and check your alias `which python`. Notice it is still 3.11? These aliases just lead to confusion.

Answer (score 7):

add below 2 lines to ./zshrc IS THE ANSWER, GIVEN THAT you already have  `eval "$(pyenv init -)"`

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PATH"
```

Trick is to let shims play its deserving part.

Comment: This is probably the most useful answer to this whole matter of Python environment management.

Comment: worked for m1. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

On MacOS Montery 12.5 there is no longer a `python` binary in `/usr/local/bin/`. A quick fix is to ensure that is a default ref that points to the system `python3`.

```
ln -s python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case shims were initialized correctly:

```
$ which python
/home/me/.pyenv/shims/python
```

Yet, similar to [richard-domingo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73759730), I was seeing:

```
$ pyenv which python
pyenv: python: command not found

The `python' command exists in these Python versions:
  3.8.13

Note: See 'pyenv help global' for tips on allowing both
      python2 and python3 to be found.
```

The problem here was that the active python version was `system`, and my system `python3` did not have a `python` alias (symlink).

Two options to fix this:

- *either* create a `python` [symlink](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html) for the system's `python3`, similar to [cmcginty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73203505), for example:

  ```
  ln -s python3 /usr/bin/python
  ```
- *or* explicitly set the python version to one of the versions listed in the error message, using e.g. `pyenv shell`, `pyenv local`, or `pyenv global`, depending on your use-case. This is explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#understanding-python-version-selection) and discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36357705) and [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/566#issuecomment-294239545).

  In this case

  ```
  pyenv local 3.8.13
  ```

  whould create/modify a `.python-version` file in the current directory.

It is really worth reading the following section in the docs: [Understanding Python version selection](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#understanding-python-version-selection).

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing the same error. I just had to follow the error message pyenv was saying:

```
Note: See 'pyenv help global' for tips on allowing both...
```

Which made me run the following command:

```
pyenv global 2.7.18 3.10.6
```

which are versions existing in my `pyenv versions`

Answer (score 4):

I had previously installed `pyenv` and then installed my required python distribution as follows:

```
pyenv install 3.7.10
```

To remove subsequent `pyenv: python :command not found` errors -- I first had to run:

```
pyenv global 3.7.10
```

That solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

when I use python with pyenv, show me:

```
/Users/zhezhezhu/.pyenv/shims/python: line 21: /usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.18/libexec/pyenv: No such file or directory
```

I solved it by :    `pyenv rehash`

Answer (score 2):

I was using Ubuntu 20.04 and it seemed like I had wrongly setup the commands in my `~/.bashrc`. I followed [configure your shell's environment for Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation):

**If your ~/.profile sources ~/.bashrc (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint):**

```
# the sed invocation inserts the lines at the start of the file
# after any initial comment lines
sed -Ei -e '/^([^#]|$)/ {a \
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
a \
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
a \
' -e ':a' -e '$!{n;ba};}' ~/.profile
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >>~/.profile

echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

If you are using **MacOs**, **Fedora**, or **CentOS**, please follow the link above. **The commands may also change in the future, depending on pyenv/os/distributions udpates**.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ubuntu 18.04 environment, using pyenv 2.2.5 here is what you need to update the `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
if ! command -v pyenv &> /dev/null
then # If no pyenv is found 
    echo "pyenv could not be found, cannot initialize env"
else
    eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
    eval "$(pyenv init -)"
    eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
fi
```

If you are using some other OS, then it may be that you need to add this to another dotfile such as `.bash_profile`. For more detailed info, check out the docs: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout

Comment: This answer worked for me on MacOS 12. I had to add `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` for it to work. Just `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` wasn't enough.