# pyenv command not found - Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, jupyter, pyenv

I already referred to this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51863225/pyenv-python-command-not-found)

I am currently using a jupyter notebook in my server (where I don't have sudo access) which has `python 2.7 kernel`.

However, I would like to add `Python >= 3.5` as the kernel. So, I was using followed the tutorial to install `Pyenv`.

The installation is successful and I get the below message in my jupyter notebook

```
WARNING: seems you still have not added 'pyenv' to the load path.

# Load pyenv automatically by adding
# the following to ~/.bashrc:

export PATH="/home/abcd/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Later, when I try to execute the below command, I get an error as shown below

```
!pyenv install --list | grep " 3\.[678]"
```

Please note that I am using `!` symbol as I am executing it from `Jupyter notebook` cell

> **/bin/sh: 1: pyenv: not found**

How can I avoid this error and make pyenv work and produce the below output

[image]

Comment: this may [help change python interpreter for jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645807/change-interpreter-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: what's the result of your `echo $PATH`?  Also, did you restart the shell `exec "$SHELL"` after adding path.

Comment: Here is the path `/home/abcd/bin:/home/abcd/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

Comment: How do I restart the shell `exec "$SHELL"`?

Comment: Acc to your $PATH, the pyenv wasn't added to it. Did you add the path in `.bashrc` ? You can also use `>> ~/.bashrc` after every export command. You may try using `!exec $SHELL` to reload shell. Maybe try doing these things from the command line itself.

Comment: I am sorry. Am new to Python and ubuntu.. May I check with you on how can I launch command line for commands? Meaning I am already in the ubuntu server.

Comment: I used `jupyter notebook` to launch the jupyter notebook.

Comment: Where can I find the `.bashrc`?

Comment: Okay, from the terminal where you use `jupyter notebook`, run the export commands by appending `>> .bashrc` to each one of them (or open `.bashrc` using any text editor and paste the commands). `.bashrc` will be at your `/home/username/`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216432/discussion-between-the-great-and-kharshit).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per the discussion in comments section, it turns out the pyenv path wasn't exported to `.bashrc`. It can be done by executing the following commands in terminal:

```
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bashrc
```

then restart the shell

```
exec "$SHELL"
```

Now, you can use pyenv to create virtual environments, then activate the environment and start working without interfering with the system environment.