# Numpy ModuleNotFoundError on pyenv python environment with Numpy installed

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling, pyenv, modulenotfounderror

I'm rather new to coding, so please bare with me if I'm not using the optimal terminology to ask this question. I've installed and set up python on my Mac using pyenv based on the following link:

https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac

I'm currently trying to execute a program, but I receive a ModuleNotFoundError on Numpy upon execution.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I've checked via terminal and ensured numpy is installed, I went through the pyenv source files and confirmed numpy is there, and tried the "python -mpip install numpy" method to no avail. I'm not sure what to do at this point, so any of your suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried typing python3 in terminal instead of just python when running the script?

Comment: Hey Chris, I confirmed that it's python3 that contains numpy installed in it, so I guess I have? I know the program I'm running is running under the same python version as the one I'm confirming has numpy installed within terminal, and that is python 3 (v 3.8.5)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the pip location with the command

```
pyenv which pip
```

And use the output to install numpy in the correct environment, for example:

```
C:\Users\username\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.5\Scripts\pip.exe install numpy
```

You can, alternatively, fix the "pip" alias as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51863225/pyenv-python-command-not-found).